# APIM Policy to store the public key and verify against it

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-policy, apim

I need to store the issuer signing key in keyvault and then verify the JWT against it through apim policy . How to do that ?

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized">
            <issuer-signing-keys>
                <key>123412341234123412341234</key>
            </issuer-signing-keys>
        </validate-jwt>
    </inbound>
</policies>
```

Comment: Please paste code as text and not as an image: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: its a just a normal example code which i copied from here : https://azure.github.io/apim-lab/apim-lab/7-security/apimanagement-7-1-JWT-Validation.html

Answer (score 1):

Use [named values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-properties?tabs=azure-portal) and configured it to get your secret from Key Vault and then use it in the policy

```
  <key>{{IssuerSigningKey}}</key>
```

[image]

[image]